# How to align multiple pgfplots vertically and horizontally in multiple columns?

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, multicol, graphs

I have just begun using LaTeX and am creating a worksheet for my students that has multiple graphs. I have used `multicol` to organize them and enumerate to number them. I have also set the width and height of each plot so they are identical. Yet when my code compiles the graphs are slightly out of alignment horizontally and vertically. Is there any easy way to fix this? Thank you

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{exercise}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{systeme}

\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{width=6cm, height=6cm, compat=1.18} 

\begin{document}
Write the equation of the lines in the following graphs.
    \begin{multicols}{3}
        \begin{enumerate}
             \item 
                \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north),>=latex]
                    \begin{axis}[
                        grid=both,
                        axis lines=middle,
                        minor tick num=1,
                        ytick distance=2,
                        xmin=-1,
                        xmax=6,
                        ymin=-8,
                        ymax=2,
                        %enlargelimits={abs=0.5},
                        axis line style={latex-latex},
                        ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white}
                            ]
                        \addplot[line width=1.5pt, domain=-1:4]{3*x-7};
                    \end{axis}
                \end{tikzpicture}
            \item 
                \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north),>=latex]
                    \begin{axis}[
                        grid=both,
                        axis lines=middle,
                        minor tick num=1,
                        ytick distance=2,
                        ymin=-1,
                        ymax=6,
                        axis line style={latex-latex},
                        ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white}
                            ]
                        \addplot[line width=1.5pt, domain=-4:4]{2};
                    \end{axis}
                \end{tikzpicture}
            \item 
                \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north),>=latex]
                    \begin{axis}[
                        grid=both,
                        axis lines=middle,
                        minor tick num=1,
                        ytick distance=2,
                        ymin=-2,
                        ymax=6,
                        axis line style={latex-latex},
                        ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white}
                            ]
                        \addplot[line width=1.5pt, domain=-1:8]{-(2/3)*x+4};
                    \end{axis}
                \end{tikzpicture}
            \item 
                \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north),>=latex]
                    \begin{axis}[
                        grid=both,
                        axis lines=middle,
                        minor tick num=1,
                        ytick distance=2,
                        ymin=-3,
                        ymax=7,
                        xmin=-4,
                        xmax=4,
                        axis line style={latex-latex},
                        ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white}
                            ]
                        \addplot[line width=1.5pt, domain=-4:4]{(4/3)*x+2};
                    \end{axis}
                \end{tikzpicture}
            \item 
                \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north),>=latex]
                    \begin{axis}[
                        grid=both,
                        axis lines=middle,
                        minor tick num=1,
                        ytick distance=2,
                        xmin=-1,
                        xmax=5,
                        axis line style={latex-latex},
                        ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white}
                            ]
                        \addplot[line width=1.5pt, domain=-1:8] coordinates{(3,-3) (3,3)};
                    \end{axis}
                \end{tikzpicture}
            \item 
                \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north),>=latex]
                    \begin{axis}[
                        grid=both,
                        axis lines=middle,
                        minor tick num=1,
                        ytick distance=2,
                        xmin=-4,
                        xmax=3,
                        axis line style={latex-latex},
                        ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white}
                            ]
                        \addplot[line width=1.5pt, domain=-4:1]{-2*x-1};
                    \end{axis}
                \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a tabulated data, use `tabular` environment instead of a mix of `multicol` and `enumerate`.

I changed the scale of all pictures to 0.8 to fit all graphs in the grid and left font size as default. It seems to look all right. I also applied the same axis range. I personally think it looks more consistent. However, the first and the third graphs vary significantly and deserves to have their own settings. I also added `trim axis left` and `trim axis right` in order to set bounding box to axes. This prevents graphs from shifting towards left or right when labels appear on edges of a picture.

Global settings of both axes and each picture are moved to preamble to avoid repetitions. For the same reason, I defined a new numeric counter `graph` to number each graph. The following line formats the counter:

```
\renewcommand*{\thegraph}{\arabic{graph})}
```

and is current set to `1)`, for example.

Here's the solution

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{exercise}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{showframe}

%%% Global settings for tikz pictures
\tikzset{
  >=latex,
  baseline={([yshift=-2.5ex]current bounding box.north)},
  trim axis left, trim axis right,
}
\pgfplotsset{
  grid=both,
  axis lines=middle,
  minor tick num=1,
  axis line style={latex-latex},
  ytick distance=2,
  ticklabel style={fill=white},   % font=\normalsize
  xmin=-4, xmax=4, ymin=-2, ymax=6,
  width=5cm, height=5cm, compat=1.18,
}
\newcounter{graph}
\renewcommand*{\thegraph}{\arabic{graph})}   % Formats the counter


\begin{document}
Write the equation of the lines in the following graphs.

\begin{figure}[tbh]
  \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % space between a number and a graph
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{}
      rc
      @{\hspace{2em}}   % Space between 1st and 2nd graph in a row
      rc
      @{\hspace{2em}}   % Space between 2st and 3rd graph in a row
      rc
    @{}}
    \stepcounter{graph}\thegraph &
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
          scale = 0.8,
        ]
          \begin{axis}[
            xmin=-2, xmax=6, ymin=-10, ymax=2,
          ]
            \addplot[line width=1.5pt, domain=-1:4]{3*x-7};
          \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    &
    \stepcounter{graph}\thegraph &
      \begin{tikzpicture}[
          scale = 0.8,
        ]
          \begin{axis}
            \addplot[line width=1.5pt, domain=-4:4]{2};
          \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    &
    \stepcounter{graph}\thegraph &
      \begin{tikzpicture}[
        scale = 0.8,
      ]
        \begin{axis}[
          xmin=-1, xmax=7,
        ]
          \addplot[line width=1.5pt, domain=-1:7]{-(2/3)*x+4};
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \\
    \rule[8pt]{0pt}{2em} % small strut
    \stepcounter{graph}\thegraph &
      \begin{tikzpicture}[
        scale = 0.8,
      ]
        \begin{axis}
          \addplot[line width=1.5pt, domain=-4:4]{(4/3)*x+2};
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
    &
    \stepcounter{graph}\thegraph &
      \begin{tikzpicture}[
        scale = 0.8,
      ]
        \begin{axis}
          \addplot[line width=1.5pt, domain=-1:8] coordinates{(3,-2) (3,6)};
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
    &
    \stepcounter{graph}\thegraph &
      \begin{tikzpicture}[
        scale = 0.8,
      ]
        \begin{axis}
          \addplot[line width=1.5pt, domain=-4:1]{-2*x-1};
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{tabular}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, how would you add the numbering of each graph in this solution? I agree the consistent scale looks nice as well.

Comment: See my changed answer. If you want a number at each graph, in this solution you just need to add more columns. However, more content in a row takes more space so I had to reduce the size of each graph. I also added trims to make sure graphs are aligned around axes excluding labels.

Answer (score 1):

First, I reduced the size of your plots.  Second, `[scale only axis]` provides more consistent results.  Finally, I expanded the bounding boxes by 5pt in both directions relative to the lower left corner of the axis.  This compensates for slight changes due to text at the edges.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{exercise}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{systeme}

\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{width=3cm, height=3cm, compat=1.18, scale only axis} 

\begin{document}
Write the equation of the lines in the following graphs.
    \begin{multicols}{3}
        \begin{enumerate}
             \item 
                \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north),>=latex]
                    \begin{axis}[
                        grid=both,
                        axis lines=middle,
                        minor tick num=1,
                        ytick distance=2,
                        xmin=-1,
                        xmax=6,
                        ymin=-8,
                        ymax=2,
                        %enlargelimits={abs=0.5},
                        axis line style={latex-latex},
                        ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white}
                            ]
                        \addplot[line width=1.5pt, domain=-1:4]{3*x-7};
                    \end{axis}
                    \path (-5pt,-5pt) (3cm+5pt,3cm+5pt);
                \end{tikzpicture}
            \item 
                \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north),>=latex]
                    \begin{axis}[
                        grid=both,
                        axis lines=middle,
                        minor tick num=1,
                        ytick distance=2,
                        ymin=-1,
                        ymax=6,
                        axis line style={latex-latex},
                        ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white}
                            ]
                        \addplot[line width=1.5pt, domain=-4:4]{2};
                    \end{axis}
                    \path (-5pt,-5pt) (3cm+5pt,3cm+5pt);
                \end{tikzpicture}
            \item 
                \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north),>=latex]
                    \begin{axis}[
                        grid=both,
                        axis lines=middle,
                        minor tick num=1,
                        ytick distance=2,
                        ymin=-2,
                        ymax=6,
                        axis line style={latex-latex},
                        ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white}
                            ]
                        \addplot[line width=1.5pt, domain=-1:8]{-(2/3)*x+4};
                    \end{axis}
                    \path (-5pt,-5pt) (3cm+5pt,3cm+5pt);
                \end{tikzpicture}
            \item 
                \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north),>=latex]
                    \begin{axis}[
                        grid=both,
                        axis lines=middle,
                        minor tick num=1,
                        ytick distance=2,
                        ymin=-3,
                        ymax=7,
                        xmin=-4,
                        xmax=4,
                        axis line style={latex-latex},
                        ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white}
                            ]
                        \addplot[line width=1.5pt, domain=-4:4]{(4/3)*x+2};
                    \end{axis}
                    \path (-5pt,-5pt) (3cm+5pt,3cm+5pt);
                \end{tikzpicture}
            \item 
                \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north),>=latex]
                    \begin{axis}[
                        grid=both,
                        axis lines=middle,
                        minor tick num=1,
                        ytick distance=2,
                        xmin=-1,
                        xmax=5,
                        axis line style={latex-latex},
                        ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white}
                            ]
                        \addplot[line width=1.5pt, domain=-1:8] coordinates{(3,-3) (3,3)};
                    \end{axis}
                    \path (-5pt,-5pt) (3cm+5pt,3cm+5pt);
                \end{tikzpicture}
            \item 
                \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north),>=latex]
                    \begin{axis}[
                        grid=both,
                        axis lines=middle,
                        minor tick num=1,
                        ytick distance=2,
                        xmin=-4,
                        xmax=3,
                        axis line style={latex-latex},
                        ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white}
                            ]
                        \addplot[line width=1.5pt, domain=-4:1]{-2*x-1};
                    \end{axis}
                    \path (-5pt,-5pt) (3cm+5pt,3cm+5pt);
                \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}``
```

[image: demo]

---

This version uses [name=border] to put the baseline on the axis itself instead of the bounding box.  You still need to expand the bounding box east and west.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{exercise}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{systeme}

\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{width=3cm, height=3cm, compat=1.18, scale only axis} 

\begin{document}
Write the equation of the lines in the following graphs.
    \begin{multicols}{3}
        \begin{enumerate}
             \item 
                \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(border.north),>=latex]
                    \begin{axis}[
                        name=border,
                        grid=both,
                        axis lines=middle,
                        minor tick num=1,
                        ytick distance=2,
                        xmin=-1,
                        xmax=6,
                        ymin=-8,
                        ymax=2,
                        %enlargelimits={abs=0.5},
                        axis line style={latex-latex},
                        ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white}
                            ]
                        \addplot[line width=1.5pt, domain=-1:4]{3*x-7};
                    \end{axis}
                    \path (-5pt,0pt) (border.north east)++(5pt,0pt);
                \end{tikzpicture}
            \item 
                \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(border.north),>=latex]
                    \begin{axis}[
                        name=border,
                        grid=both,
                        axis lines=middle,
                        minor tick num=1,
                        ytick distance=2,
                        ymin=-1,
                        ymax=6,
                        axis line style={latex-latex},
                        ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white}
                            ]
                        \addplot[line width=1.5pt, domain=-4:4]{2};
                    \end{axis}
                    \path (-5pt,0pt) (border.north east)++(5pt,0pt);
                \end{tikzpicture}
            \item 
                \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(border.north),>=latex]
                    \begin{axis}[
                        name=border,
                        grid=both,
                        axis lines=middle,
                        minor tick num=1,
                        ytick distance=2,
                        ymin=-2,
                        ymax=6,
                        axis line style={latex-latex},
                        ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white}
                            ]
                        \addplot[line width=1.5pt, domain=-1:8]{-(2/3)*x+4};
                    \end{axis}
                    \path (-5pt,0pt) (border.north east)++(5pt,0pt);
                \end{tikzpicture}
            \item 
                \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(border.north),>=latex]
                    \begin{axis}[
                        name=border,
                        grid=both,
                        axis lines=middle,
                        minor tick num=1,
                        ytick distance=2,
                        ymin=-3,
                        ymax=7,
                        xmin=-4,
                        xmax=4,
                        axis line style={latex-latex},
                        ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white}
                            ]
                        \addplot[line width=1.5pt, domain=-4:4]{(4/3)*x+2};
                    \end{axis}
                    \path (-5pt,0pt) (border.north east)++(5pt,0pt);
                \end{tikzpicture}
            \item 
                \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(border.north),>=latex]
                    \begin{axis}[
                        name=border,
                        grid=both,
                        axis lines=middle,
                        minor tick num=1,
                        ytick distance=2,
                        xmin=-1,
                        xmax=5,
                        axis line style={latex-latex},
                        ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white}
                            ]
                        \addplot[line width=1.5pt, domain=-1:8] coordinates{(3,-3) (3,3)};
                    \end{axis}
                    \path (-5pt,0pt) (border.north east)++(5pt,0pt);
                \end{tikzpicture}
            \item 
                \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(border.north),>=latex]
                    \begin{axis}[
                        name=border,
                        grid=both,
                        axis lines=middle,
                        minor tick num=1,
                        ytick distance=2,
                        xmin=-4,
                        xmax=3,
                        axis line style={latex-latex},
                        ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white}
                            ]
                        \addplot[line width=1.5pt, domain=-4:1]{-2*x-1};
                    \end{axis}
                    \path (-5pt,0pt) (border.north east)++(5pt,0pt);
                \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, did not know about the scale only axis so always great to learn something new.